# App crashes when I click signup button (using firebase )

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Whenever I click the signup button in my login page app crashes and doesn't move to the next activity.I have been stuck on this for a day now,can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Here is the code I have written for signup button method.
(`emailText` and `passwordText` are TextInputLayout)

```
 public void signup(View view){
        if(!validatePassword()|!validateEmail()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            ref.child("users").child(emailText.getEditText().getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        emailText.setError("Username or Email already exists, pick another!");
                    } else {

                            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailText.getEditText().getText().toString(), passwordText.getEditText().getText().toString())
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            } else {


                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }


                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

        }

    }
```

Logcat is showing error on 7th line i.e. ref.child(... line.
I have tried alternative for 7th line like:
`ref.child("users").child("username").addLi....`
But no progress.

Here is the log

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@1a7dad29 rejected from com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1@28fb68ae[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:592)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop.scheduleNow(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:105)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.scheduleNow(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:276)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.addEventRegistration(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:233)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:175)
        at com.example.admin.instagramclone.MainActivity.signup(MainActivity.java:66)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19903) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Comment: are you sure about this: if(!validatePassword()|!validateEmail()){
            return;
        }??

may be you intend to use || instead of '|'

which justifies the "7th" line error may be :)

Comment: No, I intend to use the '|' operator not '||' operator. And 7th line is in else statement, if statement is executed successfully. '|' is used when you want to invoke both the functions `validatePassword()` and `validateEmail()`. If I use the '||' operator it will invoke the first function and if the first function returns true, if statement gets executed and it will not invoke the second function.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I updated the latest version of firebase realtime database and the problem was fixed

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
```